# Best practice to clean up Flink application cluster on Kubernetes when the application is completed

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-batch

We are running Flink jobs on Kubernetes in Application mode, the problem is when the job is completed/stopped, the job manager container will exit but the 1. deployment for task managers 2. job manager service 3. configMap  will still be there unless we run kubectl delete to clean it up.

This is not a big deal if we stop the job manually, but in case our Flink job is a batch job which will complete sometime later, it means we need an external service to keep monitoring job manager container and clean up the rest resources when it's done, which is not very practical.

I wonder what's the best practice here? Do we support run Flink batch jobs on Kubernetes? If yes then there should be a way for the Flink job itself to clean up everything when it's completed right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running [standalone Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/) application on Kubernetes. In such mode, Flink is not aware of Kubernetes cluster. So the users have to leverage some external tools(e.g. kubectl, k8s-operator) to manage the lifecyle of Flink clusters. This means that you need to delete the TaskManager deployment, configmaps, services manually.

I think this situation could get improved via the following two ways.

1. Set the [owner reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/) for TaskManager deployment, configmaps, services to JobManager job. However, you still need to delete the Kubernetes job manually after application finished.
2. Have a try on the [native Kubernetes integration](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/). Flink will have an embedded Kubernetes client and could delete the resource automatically when application finished.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For 1.Does it mean we still need a client to keep monitoring the job status and delete the job when it's completed? Will ttlSecondsAfterFinished help in this case for auto clean up? 
For 2. Our current framework doesn't support native Kubernetes integration so it might not be a solution for us in short term.